# Repeated Characters in Array

Tags: java

How do you line up two char arrays with as many repeated characters as possible? This is what I got.

```
public class Repeat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Foo = "HELLO";
        String Boo = "VEX";

        char [] Key = new char[Foo.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < Foo.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Key.length; j++) {
                if(i < Boo.length()) {
                    Key[i] = Boo.charAt(i);

                }

            }
        }

        for(char c : Key) {
            System.out.print(c + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

It currently prints out  `V E X [ ] [ ]`

I want the Key to print out

```
V E X V E
```

so it lines up with

```
H E L L O
```

Comment: You need to follow the Java coding convention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why one might want to do something like that, but you can use the modulo operator `%` together with both the shorter and the longer string's length to achieve what you want to do. Something like this:

```
String longString = "abcde";
String shortString = "abc";
char[] array = new char[longString.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    array[i] = shortString.charAt(i % shortString.length());
}
```

If you then output the contents of `array`, you should get `abcab`.

#### How that code works

The `for` loop iterates from 0 to the length of `array` (which equals `longString.length()`) less 1. This assures that all elements of the array (0, 1, ... , `array.length() - 1`) can be initialized in the loop's body.

The statement `i % shortString.length()` determines the position of the character that should be retrieved from `shortString`. Since `i` may be greater than or equal to `shortString.length()` (which would cause an exception if used as parameter for `shortString.charAt(int)`), you have to add the modulo operator which makes sure that the parameter of `shortString.charAt(int)` stays within the range from 0 (inclusive) to `shortString.length()` (exclusive) but causes another character to be returned in every iteration.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. It'd be nice to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which allows you to build the output `String` without using an explicit loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "HELLO";
    String boo = "VEX";
    String repeated = new String(new char[foo.length() / boo.length()]).replace("\0", boo);
    repeated += boo.substring(0, foo.length() % boo.length());
    repeated = repeated.replace("", " ").trim();

    System.out.println(repeated);
}
```

**Output:**

```
V E X V E
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method for doing that repeated printing for unlimited number of strings:

```
private static void printRepeatedToLongest(String ... values) {
    int maxLen = 0;
    for (String value : values)
        if (value.length() > maxLen)
            maxLen = value.length();
    for (String value : values)
        if (value.length() == maxLen)
            System.out.println(value);
        else {
            char[] buf = new char[maxLen];
            for (int i = 0, len; i < maxLen; i += len) {
                len = Math.min(value.length(), maxLen - i);
                value.getChars(0, len, buf, i);
            }
            System.out.println(buf);
        }
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRepeatedToLongest();       // Prints nothing
    printRepeatedToLongest("");     // Prints a blank line
    printRepeatedToLongest("FOO");  // Prints the string
    printRepeatedToLongest("HELLO", "VEX");
    printRepeatedToLongest("recondite", "injure", "earthy", "taste", "calm", "minute",
                           "jealous", "level", "intend", "infamous", "men", "defeated");
}
```

*Output*

```
           <-- blank line
FOO
HELLO
VEXVE
recondite
injureinj
earthyear
tastetast
calmcalmc
minutemin
jealousje
levelleve
intendint
infamousi
menmenmen
defeatedd
```

Comment: actually, calling `printRepeatedToLongest()` would cause a `NullPointerException`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @mezzodrinker No. I ran that code. It receives an empty `String[]`, not a null value.

Comment: It does? Huh. I always thought empty varargs would equal null. Well, today I learned something new again.